# Please help me identify the grammatical part of a sentence

Tags: grammar

In the sentence below:

> His plan was to create human figures in clay——2,500 of them—— each one unique, each one a tribute, though not an exact portrait in the traditional sense.

I'm not sure what the noun phrase, "each on unique, each one a tribute, though not an exact portrait in the traditional sense." function here? Nominative absolute?

Comment: Yes, they are absolute constructions. More precisely they are the verbless analogues of the supplements "each one being unique" / "each one being a tribute".

Comment: Why does everyone on this site answer questions in the comments section? You've taken the time to write an answer so why not just post it as an answer?